# Seperated text by comma delimiter want to show first and/or second only - in a messagebox vb.net

Tags: vb.net, messagebox, delimiter

I have a csv file `032214.cvs` data in file equals 12345678,1.1234,G00  L

Message Box:

```
Dim FileReader As String
FileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Apps\CSVDATA\032214.csv")
MessageBox.Show((FileReader),"Verify Information",
MessageBoxButtons.Ok,MessageBoxIcon.Question)
```

It displays all     `12345678,1.1234,G00  L`  But I only want to display `12345678`

Answer (score 0):

Try this;

```
Dim FileReader As String
FileReader = My.Computer.FileSystem.ReadAllText("C:\Apps\CSVDATA\032214.csv")
StrToDisplay = Split(FileReader,",")(0)
MessageBox.Show((StrToDisplay),"Verify Information",
MessageBoxButtons.Ok,MessageBoxIcon.Question)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: Comes up with. Error occured when compiling VB.net script  It is VB.net sorry.

Comment: I saw the syntax is not familiar to vbscript, but I figured I'll give you the vbscript solution, and once you get the idea, you'll be able to take it from there.

Answer (score 0):

That syntax looks to me as `VB.Net` not `VBScript`, anyway, use `Split` with optional `count` argument.

```
'Split(expression[, delimiter[, count[, compare]]])
StrToDisplay = Join(Split(FileReader, ",", 2), ",")
```

Comment: Comes up with. Error occured when compiling VB.net script It is VB.net sorry.